# Where to save images of React file upload component after component will unmount?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

When componentWillUnmount hook is executed I loose the uploaded preview images. To preserve those images, I've saved them into sessionStorge so I can load them from sessionStoarge when component will be mounted. The problem is that space is limited.
Do you have any ideas where I can keep those images ? Thanks !

Comment: Any reason why you can't keep them on the backend?

Comment: If I do this, I need to download them every time when my component will be mounted, which is not good.
I've made a request for each image when the user drop/select an image from his computer, so the images are stored on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the images in indexdb.
IndexedDB is a low-level API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data, including files/blobs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API